# How to transfer data in spreadsheet into SQL database

Tags: sql, excel, database, bigdata, data-transfer

The data I have is above 1000 rows and it keeps increasing. MS Excel is already freezing.

I don't know how to migrate the data to a SQL database apart from creating a new table and inserting over 1000 rows. Inserting 1000 rows is very difficult and time consuming.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Several options in doing this: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

I have also used [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-ver16) and [Write-SQLTableData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/write-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

I personally use MySQL Database, you can just create a Database in MySQL, right click on the wizard that is most probably on the left, there will be the option to import data, import data from CSV/XLSX, click import, provide the path, it will confirm the data types (string, int, float, date time). Set names if necessary and you'll have your spreadsheet in Database.